# Capturing an event such as mouse click in Datagridview in VB

Tags: vb.net

Update 5/21/17.  Thank you for the suggestion of using a Table.  That was helpful.  I actually figured it out.  I made myinputable a global variable by declaring the Dim statement at the top and making it a Datagridview type.  Now I can turn it off in the other event that I needed to do it.

I am a novice.  I have created a Datagridview in VB 2015 to capture a bunch of data from the use. When the user is finished with the data entry, I want to store the cell values in my variables.  I do not know how to capture any event from my dynamically created datagridview "myinputable."  My code is below.  Please help.

Private Sub inputmodel()
        Dim prompt As String
        Dim k As Integer
        '
        '  first get the problem title and the number of objectives and alternatives
        '
        prompt = "Enter problem title: "
        title = InputBox(prompt)
        prompt = "Enter number of criteria: "
        nobj = InputBox(prompt)
        prompt = "Enter number of alternatives: "
        nalt = InputBox(prompt)
        '
        ' now create the table
        '
        Dim Myinputable As New DataGridView
        Dim combocol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        combocol.Items.AddRange("Increasing", "Decreaing", "Threashold")

```
    For k = 1 To 6
        If k <> 2 Then
            Dim nc As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            nc.Name = ""
            Myinputable.Columns.Add(nc)
        Else
            Myinputable.Columns.AddRange(combocol)
        End If
    Next k

    ' now add the rows and place the spreadsheet on the form

    Myinputable.Rows.Add(nobj - 1)
    Myinputable.Location = New Point(25, 50)

    Myinputable.AutoSize = True
    Me.Controls.Add(Myinputable)
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Visible = True

    Myinputable.Columns(0).Name = "Name"
    Myinputable.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Name"

    Myinputable.Columns(1).Name = "Type"
    Myinputable.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Type"

    Myinputable.Columns(2).Name = "LThresh"
    Myinputable.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Lower Threshold"
    'Myinputable.Columns(2).ValueType = co

    Myinputable.Columns(3).Name = "UThresh"
    Myinputable.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Upper Threshold"

    Myinputable.Columns(4).Name = "ABMin"
    Myinputable.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Abs. Minimum"

    Myinputable.Columns(5).Name = "ABMax"
    Myinputable.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Abs. Maximum "

    Myinputable.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "Help"

    If Myinputable.Capture = True Then
        MsgBox(" damn ")
    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: The DataGridView is primarily intended to present a *View* of the *data* to the user.  It can hold data, but there are better mechanisms for that - a DataTable. - which will also allow you to store numeric values as numeric types.  No need for any heroics - the DGV will store the data in the DataTable for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Plutonix suggests, you should start by creating a `DataTable`.  Add columns of the appropriate types to the `DataTable` and then bind it to the grid, i.e. assign it to the `DataSource` of your grid, e.g.

```
Dim table As New DataTable

With table.Columns
    .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
    .Add("Name", GetType(String))
End With

DataGridView1.DataSource = table
```

That will automatically add the appropriate columns to the grid if it doesn't already have any, or you can add the columns in the designer and set their `DataPropertyName` to tell them which `DataColumn` to bind to.  As the user makes changes in the grid, the data will be automatically pushed to the underlying `DataTable`.

When you're done, you can access the data via the `DataTable` and even save the lot to a database with a single call to the `Update` method of a data adapter if you wish.